# Can no longer assign class property values using this["propertyName"] in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript, flex4

Given a dynamic or non-dynamic class like the following:

```
package {
  public class MyClass {
    public var myProperty:String;
    public var myBooleanProperty:Boolean;

    public function MyClass() {}
  }
}
```

Flex 3 allows you to assign a value to myProperty like this:

```
myClassInstance["myProperty"] = "myValue";
myClassInstance["myBooleanProperty"] = true;
```

I regularly parse XML to get property names and their values then update correlated classes using this technique; however, Flex 4 no longer allows assigning the boolean property.  I don't have a work-around.

If you trace the results:

```
trace(myClassInstance.myProperty) // Returns "myValue"
trace(myClassInstance.myBooleanProperty) // Returns null
```

Can someone explain what has changed and how to work-around the issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
               >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                var c:MyClass = new MyClass();
                c["myBooleanProperty"] = true;
                trace(c["myBooleanProperty"]);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```

This outputs "true" with the Flex SDK 4.1.
There may be something else wrong in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dictionary](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform//reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html) class instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you simply tried to do this?

```
  myClassInstance.myBooleanProperty = true;
```

This is actually the standard way of assigning a value to a public property in AS3.